# How do I pass arguments to a grunt browserify transform (hbsfy)?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js, browserify, grunt-browserify

I'm using hbsfy (handlebars templating package) as a transform for browserify in a grunt file. How do I pass the `-t` or `--transform` argument to the hbsfy transform?

```
grunt.initConfig({
  browserify: {
   build: {
    src: 'src/js/app.js',
    dest: 'app.js',
    options: {
      transform: ['browserify-shim', 'hbsfy'],
      browserifyOptions: {
        debug: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

If I were to use browserify conventionally the code would look like:

```
browserify -t [ hbsfy -t ] main.js > bundle.js
```

How do I get the -t when using grunt-browserify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at some of the existing answered issues for grunt-browserify, the following resolved my issue:

```
 options: {
   transform: ['browserify-shim', ['hbsfy', {'t':[]}]],
 },
```

I have added hbsfy as an array where the second argument is an options object which contains the empty t option. this allows me to simulate `hbsfy -t` in grunt-browserify.

I hope this helps others with the same issue.